# Cencom Controller with OEM Harness on Ford PIU

Tags: ford, wiring, modification, wiring-harness

Does anyone know where Ford intends for the Cencom controller to be mounted when using the OEM lighting harness in a Ford Interceptor Utility (PIU)? 2017 specifically.

The wiring diagrams in the upfitter manual suggest that it might be on the driver's side of the rear cargo area, but looking for confirmation so I don't have to remove any more panels than absolutely necessary.